# Cannot save data using C# code and Multitier architecture

Tags: c#

This code always ends up returning false:

```
tblDars tblDrs = new tblDars();
tblDrs.ID = Convert.ToInt32(txt_subjectID.Text);
tblDrs.Name = txt_subject.Text;
tblDrs.Vahed = Convert.ToInt32(txt_units.Text);
if (!Data.insertSubject(tblDrs)) 
{
    // Cannot save data
}
```

I am using pre-written stored procedures to save data. I have a class called Database:

```
public class Database
{

    SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["School"].ConnectionString);
    public Database()
    { }
//begin insertSubject
    public bool insertSubject(tblDars tbldrs)
    {
        sc.Open();
        try
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.Connection = sc;
            command.CommandText = "InsertDars";
            SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter("@id", tbldrs.ID);
            SqlParameter param2 = new SqlParameter("@Name", tbldrs.Name);
            SqlParameter param3 = new SqlParameter("@Vahed", tbldrs.Vahed);

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            sc.Close();
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (sc.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                sc.Close();
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    //end insertSubject
}
```

Also, the code for the tblDars class is as follows:

```
public class tblDars
{
    public tblDars()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
    }
    private int id;
    private string name;
    private int vahed;

    public int ID
    {
        set { id = value; }
        get { return id; }
    }
    public string Name
    {
        set { name = value; }
        get { return name; }
    }
    public int Vahed
    {
        set { vahed = value; }
        get { return vahed; }
    }
}
```

Already, I tried to save another form (with more fields)'s data using the same procedure. It was a failure. Where is the problem?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: That's because you swallow the exception and return false. Check what exception you get at `catch (Exception ex)`.

Comment: This has nothinhg to do with multi tiered architecture and all to do with you ignoring proper debugging. DO not throw the exception away. Read it. the error is in your data access code and - well - that is the part we can not check (as we do not see the stored procedure). I am sure once you actually care to read the exception you will look into the mirror and just fix the issue.

Comment: The exception most likely happens on command.ExecuteNonQuery(), so what about showing your stored procedure? Plus I'll add I don't think it deserves downvotes.

Comment: Add the parameters (param1, param2, param3) to your command.

Comment: @CodeCaster how can I check for ex.Message? This is a web app and I have no idea if I can open a message box or something.

Comment: my stored procedure: `ALTER proc [dbo].[InsertDars] (@id int,@Name nvarchar(50),@Vahed int)
as
begin
insert into tblDars values (@Name,@Vahed) 
end`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are never adding the parameters to your `SQLCommand`. Assuming your parameters are valid your code should look something like this:

```
try
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.Connection = sc;
    command.CommandText = "InsertDars";
    SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter("@id", tbldrs.ID);
    SqlParameter param2 = new SqlParameter("@Name", tbldrs.Name);
    SqlParameter param3 = new SqlParameter("@Vahed", tbldrs.Vahed);

    /*NEW*/
    command.Parameters.Add(param1);
    command.Parameters.Add(param2);
    command.Parameters.Add(param3);

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

alternatively you could write it like this:

```
try
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.Connection = sc;
    command.CommandText = "InsertDars";

    //watch for appropriate SqlDbType
    //reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.sqldbtype(v=vs.110).aspx
    command.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = tbldrs.ID;
    command.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = tbldrs.Name;
    command.Parameters.Add("@Vahed", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = tbldrs.Vahed;

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Are you converting or something using SqlDbType.Int and SqlDbType.VarChar?